# Connexion between hadoop and neo4j

Tags: hadoop, neo4j

I am trying to make a connection between hadoop and neo4j , so that I could import my graph and store it into neo4j . I found this code but it gives me error , can anyone please help me

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.IndexHits;
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.MapUtil;
import org.neo4j.index.lucene.unsafe.batchinsert.LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileSystemAbstraction;
import org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserter;
import org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterIndex;
import org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterIndexProvider;
import org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters;


public class Neo4jMassiveInsertion {

    private BatchInserter inserter = null;
    private BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = null;
    private BatchInserterIndex nodes = null;
    protected FileSystemAbstraction fs;
    private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType {
        SIMILAR
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Neo4jMassiveInsertion test = new Neo4jMassiveInsertion();

        test.startup("/home/salma/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.0.3/bin/neo4j");
        test.createGraph("/home/salma/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data/test.txt");
        test.shutdown();
    }
    public void startup(String storeDir) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("The Neo4j database is now starting . . . .");
        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
        config.put("cache_type", "none");
        config.put("use_memory_mapped_buffers", "true");
        config.put("neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "200M");
        config.put("neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory", "1000M");
        config.put("neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory", "250M");
        config.put("neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory", "250M");

        inserter = BatchInserters.inserter(storeDir,config);
        indexProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider(inserter);
        nodes = indexProvider.nodeIndex("nodes", MapUtil.stringMap("type", "exact"));
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        System.out.println("The Neo4j database is now shuting down . . . .");
        if(inserter != null) {
            indexProvider.shutdown();
            inserter.shutdown();
            indexProvider = null;
            inserter = null;
        }
    }

    public void createGraph(String datasetDir) {
        System.out.println("Creating the Neo4j database . . . .");
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(datasetDir)));
            String line;
            int lineCounter = 1;
            Map<String, Object> properties;
            IndexHits<Long> cache;
            long srcNode, dstNode;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(lineCounter > 4) {
                    String[] parts = line.split("\t");
                    cache = nodes.get("nodeId", parts[0]);
                    if(cache.hasNext()) {
                        srcNode = cache.next();
                    }
                    else {
                        properties = MapUtil.map("nodeId", parts[0]);
                        srcNode = inserter.createNode(properties);
                        nodes.add(srcNode, properties);
                        nodes.flush();
                    }
                    cache = nodes.get("nodeId", parts[1]);
                    if(cache.hasNext()) {
                        dstNode = cache.next();
                    }
                    else {
                        properties = MapUtil.map("nodeId", parts[1]);
                        dstNode = inserter.createNode(properties);
                        nodes.add(dstNode, properties);
                        nodes.flush();
                    }
                    inserter.createRelationship(srcNode, dstNode, RelTypes.SIMILAR, null);
                }
                lineCounter++;
            }
            reader.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/io/fs/FileSystemAbstraction
    at Neo4jMassiveInsertion.startup(Neo4jMassiveInsertion.java:55)
    at Neo4jMassiveInsertion.main(Neo4jMassiveInsertion.java:41)`

Comment: Soooo... kinda hard to figure out where your error is: You included some code without line numbers, and then your errors reference line numbers but no code. Plus, "why isn't my code working" questions are typically closed as off-topic. It would really help to edit your question, before it ends up being closed.

Comment: It doesn't matter what's in your code there because your problem is  definitely with application building. Class `FileSystemAbstraction` was available during building but wasn't available after that. Try to configure your CLASSPATH properly or create fat jar to run your application.